# Fade popup when user clicks anywhere in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need was when a popup comes and user clicks any where in the document except the popup, the popup should fadeout.

I have tried out with target.attr method, but failed in Mozilla.

IS there any Idea ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [fadeout](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method and [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

Something like :

```
jQuery("#yourpoup").click(function(){ return false; });
jQuery(document).one("click", function() { jQuery("#yourpoup").fadeOut(); });
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124684/jquery-how-click-anywhere-outside-of-the-div-the-div-fades-out) question, using this is better then using bind.

Comment: i need was, fadeout when user clicks anywhere in the body rather than the popup.

Comment: You have a typo: "one" instead of "on". I tried to fix it, but since it's only one char (but an important one!), Stackoverflow won't let me!

Comment: No it should be one, check the provided link.

Comment: OK, the error was in the description, not the code! :) Thanks, I wasn't aware of this useful method!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a JQuery plugin for click outside, this will allow you to handle the click even for everything BUT the pop up.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/

```
$("#yourpopup").bind( "clickoutside", function(event){
$(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your pop-up is a JQuery Dialog, you can see this thread:

[jQuery UI - Close Dialog When Clicked Outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554779/jquery-ui-close-dialog-when-clicked-outside/10988431#10988431)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery as example, assumed `$popup` is the your popup element

```
$('body').click(function(){
    // hide the popup here
});

$popup.click(function(e) {
    // do something here if needed
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The key is when click in the popup, stop bubble the event to body, so will not fire the function attached to body.