# Undo function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to 'undo' functions in jQuery? Let me explain.. I have a function which recreates exactly the select html tag. As you know with a select tag, clicking on a list item select that one, when clicking outside the select tag, the whole dropdown list closes. The selecting works fine, but the closing isn't. I though this would work with the `event.stopPropagation()` event object but it doesn't. Is there any other solution for this?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cmAtc/

Comment: Not as such, no -- you have to build your own "undo" functions.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't just use a `<select>`? To have the `<ul>` close when the user clicks outside, I'd recommend looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124684/jquery-how-click-anywhere-outside-of-the-div-the-div-fades-out)

Comment: @jbabey CSS styling, possibly.

Comment: If you're working with a plugin, it should have a destroy method that restores it to the original markup.

Comment: @jbabey clicking the list opens another div with new options etc.. For this very project a unordered list is better, although i would also just use the <select> if it was for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really nothing like what you are asking for that is built into jQuery natively.  You have to do it on your own.

My suggestion would be to bind to the document:

```
$(document).on('click', function () {
    $(".dropdownlist li").parent().children(":not(.selected)").hide();
});
```

You already have the `stopPropagation` that would prevent this from being triggered when you click the list too.

http://jsfiddle.net/cmAtc/1/

Comment: Wouldn't the event have to be passed as an argument?  Would resolving to window.event always work?

Comment: I had something similar with :not(.selected) but the issue is that everything disappears when clicking outside the <ul>

Comment: @user1901096 what do you mean by *everything*?  Did you try my jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried your jsfiddle. I meant that when the <ul> is expanded and I click outside of it the whole <ul> closes and all is left is the red border whereas the selected <li> should be visible.

Comment: @user1901096 that doesn't happen to me; does it happen in a specific browser?

Comment: All browsers I've tested; Chrome v21 and FF v14 on Mac and IE8 in Windows.

Comment: @user1901096 I understand now.  Problem is the `.removeClass` is done and then you never select an element again.  This took a bit more updating: http://jsfiddle.net/cmAtc/2/

Comment: Works properly now. Thanks for the solution!